# Query data depends on data from other table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get data from a table which is only related through two different tables. For example, I have information "dataA" and need to get information "dataD".

[image: table data relationship]

How do I write a query to display dataA and dataD as they relate? I don't want to display all instances of dataD, just the ones that related to dataB and then to dataA. I'm sorry if this doesn't make enough sense.

Comment: How are dataA and dataD related? There is no relation I can see from the pic you posted

Comment: I might not be explaining this properly, sorry. Fairly new to databases. Table1 has dataA and dataB. Table2 has dataC and the same dataB as in Table1. Table 3 has dataD and the same dataC as in Table 2.

Comment: Are `dataA` and `dataB` separate columns in `Table1`, or do they represent separate rows?

Comment: They represent separate columns. I guess the picture would make you think otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll use JOINs to do this. Specifically, in this case, a LEFT OUTER JOIN is your best bet. Something like:

```
SELECT
    Table1.dataA,
    Table3.dataD
FROM
    Table1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.dataB = Table2.dataB
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.dataC = Table3.dataC
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on the assumption that the "data" entries you put under each table name represent columns in the table, this is fairly simple:

```
select dataA
  ,    dataD
from   Table1 t1
    join Table2 t2
         on t1.dataB = t2.dataB
    join Table3 t3
         on T2.dataC = t3.dataC
```

If you need all the `dataA` regardless of whether there's a matching `dataD` (or other intervening column) you would change where I wrote `'join'` to `'left join'`.

And your question makes plenty of sense.  :)  I was just a little unclear from the diagram what you had in mind.